# Does Visual Studio Publish to Azure Website Cause Whole Site to Recycle?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

We've recently launched a new website in Azure (i.e. Azure Websites) and as is typical with new launches we've had to deploy a few tweaks to fix minor issues shortly after launch.

We want to use Slots in the long run but this is not possible at the moment. Hence we are deploying to the live site. It's a fairly busy site with a good amount of traffic and obviously want to keep downtime to am minimum.

We are using Visual Studio to publish file changes to Azure but have noticed that even if we publish a relatively insignificant single file the whole site goes down and struggles to come back up. I was assuming that publishing a single file would literally just replace that file on the file system but it's behaving more like it recycles the application pool (or Azure equivalent) for the site. The type of files I've been publishing have been Razor views, hence would not typically cause a recycle.

Does anyone know what actually happens under the hood of VS Publish and if there is a way to avoid this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: this happens even without azure. it is how .NET works. when IIS for instance detects a change, the app pool recycles thus having to recompile again. but with DNX (I think, I could be wrong), this no longer will be the case. But for the full blown .NET Framework, yes - this will happen and is expected

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. In my experience that's not strictly true. That would be the case if you edited the web.config or deployed an updated assembly or other specific file type, but modifying a single CSHTML Razor file should not cause the site to reload. That file should be parsed and loaded dynamically "just-in-time" i.e. on first use. If I run the site locally in IIS and simply change a Razor file that doesn't then cause the whole site to reload, just the first page that uses that Razor file.

Comment: right, its not always 100% ... but most of the time :)

Comment: I just tried saving the file directly through the Visual Studio Azure "explorer" but that didn't even seem to reflect the change so I'm not sure what's happening there.

Comment: I've now managed to copy the file using FTP. The whole site did not  reload and the page in question took a couple of extra seconds to load. As should be the case. So it seems VS Publish does more than just a file replace. I'd be interested if anybody knows of a resource that explains the exact mechanics under the hood of a VS Publish to Azure?

Comment: again - those couple of extra seconds is where .NET is recompiling the code. it knows there has been a change in the bytecode and has to start recompiling/JIT'ing. :)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this using a basically clean new MVC app (https://github.com/KuduApps/Dev14_Net46_Mvc5), and I did not see this behavior. The Index.html view has a hit count based on a static, which would tell us if the app or the page got restarted (or if that specific page got recompiled).

Then the test is to publish it, make a change to some *other* view (about.cshtml), and publish again. WHen doing this and hitting Index.cshtml, the count keeps going up, and there is minimal slowdown.

If you see it getting restarted after a view change, I suggest using [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to look at the files in site\wwwroot before/after the publish, and check what has a newer timestamp (e.g. check web.config, bin folder, ...).

Comment: Interesting. I'll give that a try. I can only say what I see though. FTP does not cause an issue, VS Publish does (for me, for this project, on a site under heavy load). I'll try to replicate on a different test site but I probably won't be able to recreate the exact scenario. It may not be a full app recycle but something is happening. I had to Restart the Web App through the Azure portal as it just didn't come back up. After the restart the site loaded fairly quickly, so it's not as though I'd introduced an error to cause the app to fail. I'll update here if I find anything. Thanks again.